# Error backing up MySQL table with yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying to make a back-up of a MySQL table with the code below:

```
public function actionOut() {
    $tableName  = 'medication';
    $backupFile = \Yii::$app->basePath.'/patients/yourtable.sql';
    $query = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName";
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->execute();
}
```

I am getting an error that I cannot create/write to the file, the `\Yii::$app->basePath` is not well formatted and an error about `cxampphttdocsfront` -  `c:/xampp/httdocs/front`. How can I find the `web` folder for console apps?

Comment: I can't tell exactly what your question is. It sounds like you are passing in bad data.

Comment: When I run this action I have the error can not create/write to file.it is a console action of yii2

Comment: Improved formatting and general grammer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use code below:

```
<?php

$backupFile = \Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'patients' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $tableName . '.sql';
// or
$backupFile = \Yii::$app->basePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'patients' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $tableName . '.sql';
```

I will work correctly on both Windows & Linux.

Comment: I use this $backupFile =  str_replace("\\",'/',Yii::$app->basePath).'/web/patients/'.date('Y-m-d_H_m_s').'.sql'; As I notice there is a problem with "\" at dos command line